# Show that Gamma Distribution (standardised) tends to Normal Distribution.

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, definite-integrals, characteristic-functions

I am trying to show, using characteristic functions, that the Gamma distribution with shape parameter $\alpha$ and rate parameter $\beta$ tends to the Normal Distribution (when standardised appropriately).

##### What I have attempted so far:

The Gamma distribution density, expectation, and variance:

$$
f(x) = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}
\quad\quad\quad
\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{\alpha}{\beta} 
\quad\quad\quad
\mathbb{V}[X] = \frac{\alpha}{\beta^2} 
$$

I then standardise the random variable:

$$
Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} 
= \frac{X- \alpha/\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha/\beta^2}}
= \frac{X- \alpha/\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha}/\beta}
$$

**This next step is where I am stuck**. I want to compute the characteristic function of $Z$, however I am unable to do the integral.

$$
\varphi_Z(t)
= \mathbb{E}[e^{itZ}] 
= \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(it \cdot \frac{X-\alpha/\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha}/\beta}\right) \right]
= \int_{\mathbb{R^+}} e^{it \cdot \frac{X-\alpha/\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha}/\beta}} \cdot \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}dx 
$$

I believe the end result should be:

$$
\varphi_Z(t)
= e^{-it\sqrt{\alpha}} \left(1- \frac{it}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\right)^{-\alpha}
$$

If someone could help with the integral that would be greatly appreciated.

##### Assuming the characteristic function I gave is correct:

We can then take the natural logarithm of the c.f. and use the Taylor series for $\ln(1-x) = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\ln(\varphi_Z(t)) 
&= -it\sqrt{\alpha} - \alpha\ln\left( 1 - \frac{it}{\sqrt{\alpha}} \right) \\
&= -it\sqrt{\alpha} 
- \alpha \left( -\frac{it}{\sqrt{\alpha}} 
- \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{it}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\right)^2
- \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{it}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\right)^3 - \cdots \right) \\
&= -it\sqrt{\alpha} 
+ \alpha \left( \frac{it}{\sqrt{\alpha}} 
- \frac{t^2}{2 \alpha}
+ \mathcal{O}(\alpha^{-1}) \right) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Taking the limit as $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$, we arrive at $-\frac{t^2}{2}$, implying that:

$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{itZ}] \rightarrow e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}
$$

Which is the characteristic function of the standard normal distribution.

Is the rest of my working correct ?

Comment: No need to solve the integral; just take nonrandom constants out of the expectation:
$$E[e^{it\frac{X-\alpha/\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha}/\beta}}]=e^{-it\sqrt{\alpha}}\underbrace{E[e^{i(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\alpha}/\beta})X}]}_{=\varphi_X((\frac{t}{\sqrt{\alpha}/\beta}))}=e^{-it\sqrt{\alpha}}\bigg(1-\frac{it}{\beta\sqrt{\alpha}/\beta}\bigg)^{-\alpha}=e^{-it\sqrt{\alpha}}\bigg(1-\frac{it}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\bigg)^{-\alpha}$$

Comment: @Snoop thank you very much. Do you also know if my use of the Big-O notation is correct in the last line of the expressions for $\ln{(\varphi_Z(t))}$ ?